# Explorer thumbnails (winXP)

Tags: c++, image, thumbnails, windows-explorer

I have a file format I need to be able to show in explorer thumbnails. Since the target system is windows XP, the Vista PreviewHandler API will not be suitable. Ill be using c++.

How would I do it?

Comment: ...and your question is what, exactly? What API's have you looked at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to register a shell extension for your file type. The extension contains code that extracts/generates the thumbnail by implementing the IExtractImage interface.

See: [IExtractImage Interface on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761848(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: http://www.angelfire.com/80s/philipsoft/files/ThumbExtract.htm I found this based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/reliak/moonpdf/tree/master/ext/sumatra/src/previewer is perfect example.

To build both x86 and x64 versions of DLL I use VS 2010 with SP1 along with Win7 x64 SDK (for `<thumbcache.h>`) installed on Windows 7 x64. Builded DLLs works fine on Win7 and Win10 of either bitness.

Also don't forget `/MD` linker flag to avoid necessity to install *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)* on WinXP.

Next lines may be added to `"targetver.h"` to avoid import and using of new functions from newer versions of Windows system DLLs (say, there is no `RegDeleteTreeW` in WinXP's `advapi.dll`):

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <winsdkver.h>
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Additionally it has implementation of previewer for some file formats, but related interfaces can be completely omitted in your implementation.